# How can I find column level references to a table?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table called `IdMap` under schema `ABC_OWNER`. I have a stored procedure called `sp_MyProcedure` that has this query, and this is in schema `XYZ_OWNER`:

```
SELECT M.IssueId
FROM IdMap M Join Product P on M.IssueId=P.IssueId
```

I would like to write a query that will tell me all references to `IdMap` and specifically which columns are being referenced. So the results of this script would tell me that `IssueID` of table `IdMap` is being referenced by stored procedure `sp_MyProcedure`.

I tried querying in the `all_dependencies` table and also against `all_objects`, but I don't know how to get into this at the column level. I am coming from a SQL Server background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with Oracle at this moment. Since 11g oracle considers column usage information for invalidating objects but as far as I know this information is not officially available outside of the Oracle kernel.

Answer (score 2):

Try Rob Van Wijk's [DBA_DEPENDENCY_COLUMNS](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2008/10/dbadependencycolumns.html):

```
create user abc_owner identified by abc_owner;
create table abc_owner.IdMap(IssueId number, a number);
create table abc_owner.Product(IssueId number, a number);

create user xyz_owner identified by xyz_owner;
grant select on abc_owner.IdMap to xyz_owner;
grant select on abc_owner.Product to xyz_owner;

create or replace procedure xyz_owner.sp_myProcedure is
    v_issue_id number;
begin
    SELECT M.IssueId
    into v_issue_id
    FROM abc_owner.IdMap M Join abc_owner.Product P on M.IssueId=P.IssueId;
end;
/

select name, referenced_name, referenced_column
from sys.dba_dependency_columns
where owner in ('ABC_OWNER', 'XYZ_OWNER');


NAME            REFERENCED_NAME  REFERENCED_COLUMN
----            ---------------  -----------
SP_MYPROCEDURE  PRODUCT          ISSUEID
SP_MYPROCEDURE  IDMAP            ISSUEID
```